# Appengine Apps Vs Google bot web crawler

Tags: python, google-app-engine, seo, web-crawler, bots

i built an appengine web app cricket.hover.in. The web app consists of about 15k url's
linked in it, But even after a long time of my launch, no pages are indexed on google.

Any base link place on my root site hover.in are being indexed with in minutes.
but i placed the same link home page of root site a long back. but its of no use.

can any one analyse , if there is any issue with cricket.hover.in or 
if bots have any issues with Google app engine

actually tested the url using labs app of webmaster tools of google there the return is fine and html is clear.

but when tested the same (cricket.hover.in) at the following urls its showing different results of failure

www.dnsqueries.com/en/googlebot_simulator.php

www.smart-it-consulting.com/internet/google/googlebot-spoofer/

but if i test some of my php or word press links at the above url's the results are good and fine.

---

Sorry my mistake in question, excuse me for misleading. the domain is cricket.trak.in/, its referred from the base URL trak.in. made the mistake in half mind of not finding a solution for the issue after a long investigation. please check with this domain.

submitted site map 3 days back it almost submitted 22k uri in total, but by the present day indexed count is still 0.

secondly cricket.trak.in itself doesn't return 15k uri, what i mean is the site in total if crawled would return about 15k uri.

Answer (score 2):

Well, from this corner of the cyberspace, there is no such domain cricket.hover.in.

```
$ dig cricket.hover.in.
; <<>> DiG 9.6.1-P2 <<>> cricket.hover.in.
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 30665
```

I'd also guess that a URL that returns 15k `href`s is considered utterly useless spam by many spiders which will ignore it even if they can reach it.

Comment: @msw, I think the typical spider _will_ collect such a URL (if reachable, of course -- we've both noticed DNS isues -- and especially if properly sitemap-ped), and index its contents, even though it will probably have abysmally low rank.

Answer (score 1):

Does your site have proper [sitemaps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitemaps) and have you pushed them to Google and other search engines?  I can't check because `http://cricket.hover.in` gives me a 404, so it could be a DNS problem.  What happens when you point your browser to that URL?